# Basequery object returned instead of model object from sqlalchemy query.filter

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two lines in my flask code that are making dbase calls.  This line:

```
articles += Entries.query.filter(and_(Entries.id == article.article_id, Entries.tags.like(search_string))) # @UndefinedVariable
```

returns a Models.Entries object.

Whereas this line :

```
articles.append(Entries.query.filter(Entries.id == 3)) # @UndefinedVariable
```

returns a Basequery object.  I need a Models.Entries object!  What might be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `articles` is a list, adding to a list is basically equivalent to `articles.extend(other_iterable)`.  A `Query` is iterable: iterating it, returning results.

In the second example, you are not executing the query, you are appending it to the list.  The equivalent code to `+=` would use `extend`, not `append`:

```
articles.extend(Entries.query.filter_by(id=3))
```

---

It looks like you're querying single items by id.  Rather than performing multiple queries and collecting the results, perform one query over a list of ids and get the results directly.

```
articles = Entries.query.filter(Entries.id.in_([1, 2, 3, 4])).all()
```